# matrix index notation in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, matrix, indexing

Can I index a multidimensional array with a single index?

Ex:

> in memory, a multidimensional array is indexed like a single array
>   (example in a matrix 2x2, matrix[1][1] is the fourth element of array,
>   "matrix[3]") Is there a system to use this notation automatically? I
>   want write matrix[3] instead of matrix[1][1]: is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily use a single index or have two methods according to how you want to access data. The method that accepts two indices could be [row-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Row-major_order) or [column-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order) according to how the data will be accessed or used. Of course to do it you will need to store the matrix in a monodimensional array. Eg:

```
class Matrix {
  int data[W*H];

  int get(int i) { return data[i]; }
  int get(int x, int y) { return data[y*W+x]; }
}
```

Comment: Same principle applies up to any arbitrary dimension. The only things that changes is `int data[W*H*D]` and `int get(int x, int y, int z) { return data[W*H*z + W*y + x] }`.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding an working example with @Jack's answer: 
For row major and language `C` (not c++) but thing works same!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define R 2
#define C 2
int main(){
  int data1[R*C]={ 1, 2,
                   3, 4
                 };
  int data2[R*C]={ 3, 5,
                   7, 8
                 };
  int result[R*C]={0 };
  int r,c;
  for(r=0; r< R ; r++){
     for(c=0; c< C ; c++){
      result[r*C + c]= data1[r*C + c]  + data2[r*C + c];
     }
  }
  printf("\nMatrix SUM\n");
  for(r=0; r< R ; r++){
     for(c=0; c< C ; c++){
      printf("%-3d ",result[r*C + c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
Matrix SUM
4   7   
10  12
```

you can see it working at [**codpade**](http://codepad.org/s9pNKx9N)

You can use macro to keep index expression clean like below

```
#define INDEX(r, c)  r*C + c
```

use macro like below:

```
data2[INDEX(r,c)];
```

Can you notice although all arrays in my example are one dimensional but my codding style is like i am working with 2-D matrix. This is not magic but 2D arrays are implemented in similar fashion under the hood at compiler level.